# SQL - Unable to get the decimals right for the percentage with CAST or STR function

Tags: sql, decimal, percentage

Any help is appreciated. I would like the values to show 0.0%. I tried all the following methods but getting error messages:

- `STR(ROUND(([Future]*100.0/Total), 2) as decimal(5,1)) + '%' as 'Percentage'`

  - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'
- `cast(ROUND(([Future]*100.0/Total), 2) as decimal(5,1)) + '%' AS 'Percentage'`

  - Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
- `CAST(ROUND(([Future]*100.0/Total), 2) as decimal(5,1)) AS 'Percentage'`

  - This gives me the desired result (0.0), but without the % symbol.
- `str(ROUND(([Future]*100.0/Total), 2)) + '%' AS ‘Percentage’`

  - This works but without the decimals (0%)

Not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `STR(CAST(ROUND(([Future]*100.0/Total), 2) as decimal(5,1))) + '%' as 'Percentage'` ?

Comment: It would help to tell us what language you're writing in, and to tag the question with the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Hi Raphael, Thanks for the quick reply...It works but it does not give me any decimals. It rounds off to whole number, eg. 50% instead of 50.1%

Comment: Hi Eric, sorry I could not find any option to choose a language, etc...I will look out for it next time.

Comment: You should specify your programming language as a "tag" below your question. Try to edit your question and add a tag. And if you can't do that then at least post a comment telling what language you're using.

Comment: I also tried CONVERT(varchar(10), ROUND(Future*100.0/Total, 1)) + '%' AS Percentage - This gives an error message "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar."